# How to detect the second finger touch on an ImageView?

Tags: android

How can I detect multitouch events? The code im trying is:

```
ImageView im = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
im.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
        Log.e("case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN","case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN");
        break;
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        Log.e("case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN","case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN");
        break;
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        Log.e("case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP","case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP");
        break;
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        Log.e("case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE","case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE");
        break;
    }
    return false;
  }
});
```

It detects the first touch and the output in the log cat is MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN. How to know whether a second touch has taken place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do it, so u can choose one of many here some link have write a complete application  to handle multi touch.

[multitouch](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/06/making-sense-of-multitouch.html)

[multi-touch-handling](http://www.mysecretroom.com/www/programming-and-software/android-multi-touch-handling)

Answer (score 2):

You should add follwing line to imageView1 in your xml layout file:

```
android:longClickable="true"
```

This will enable long clicks and other events will be received too.